# preserveAspectRatio doesn't seem to work in feImage

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I am trying to get the same effect as when using `background-size: cover` in CSS, but by using SVG filters - `feImage` in particular.

```css
div {
  width: 10em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: gold
}

.svg { filter: url(#f) }

.css {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1705339613128-28b8d900fb52?w=600) 50%/ cover
}

svg[height='0'] { position: fixed }
```

```html
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <filter id='f' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' primitiveUnits='objectBoundingBox'>
    <feImage xlink:href='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1705339613128-28b8d900fb52?w=400' 
             preserveAspectRatio='xMidyMid meet'/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<em>Result using SVG filter</em>
<div class='svg'></div>

<em>Desired result should look like</em>
<div class='css'></div>
```

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio#feimage), `preserveAspectRatio='xMidyMid meet'` should be the default, so I shouldn't even need to add it, but not even adding it seems to work.

I also shouldn't even need to set the `width` and `height`, as they should default to the filter area - also [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/height#feimage).

What am I missing here? How can I make that `feImage` cover the entire div/ filter area without distortion (`preserveAspectRatio='none'` achieves the cover part, but introduces distortion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want xMid**Y**Mid and slice. Firefox will log an error in the Javascript console to tell you that xMidyMid is not valid. SVG is case sensitive and you want to slice off the sides of the image and use the height to fill it rather than the width.

```css
div {
  width: 10em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: gold
}

.svg { filter: url(#f) }

.css {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1705339613128-28b8d900fb52?w=600) 50%/ cover
}

svg[height='0'] { position: fixed }
```

```html
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <filter id='f' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%' primitiveUnits='objectBoundingBox'>
    <feImage xlink:href='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1705339613128-28b8d900fb52?w=400' 
             preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid slice'/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<em>Result using SVG filter</em>
<div class='svg'></div>

<em>Desired result should look like</em>
<div class='css'></div>
```

Comment: I facepalmed. But I'm relieved it was such an easy fix. Thanks!